# React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called, but I can't see any hooks being called conditonally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using

- ReactJS 16.14.0

I have a React functional component that relies on data stored in context to render correctly, some of this data needs additional processing before display and some additional data needs fetching. the component is throwing the **React has detected a change in the order of Hooks** error, I have read the react docs on the rules of hooks as well as having a good look through SO but I can't work out why I get the error. I have shortened the code below to keep it brief.

```
    const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
    const [ mainContact, setMainContact ] = useState(undefined);
    const [ mainAddress, setMainAddress ] = useState(undefined);
    const [ thisLoading, setThisLoading ] = useState(true);
    const { organisation, addresses, loading } = useProfileState();


    useEffect(() => {
        setThisLoading(true);
        if(organisation && addresses && !loading) {
            Promise.all([getMainContact(), getMainAddress()])
            .then(() => {
                setThisLoading(false);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                console.log("Failed getting address/contact info");
                setThisLoading(false);
            })
        }
    }, [organisation, addresses, loading])


    const getMainContact = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            apiService.getData(`/organisation/users/${organisation.mainContact}`)
            .then(mainContact => {
                setMainContact(mainContact);
                return resolve();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                enqueueSnackbar(error, { variant: 'error' });
                return reject();
            })
        })
    }

    const getMainAddress = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let mainAddress = addresses.find(addr => addr.id === organisation.mainAddress)
            if(mainAddress !== undefined) {
                setMainAddress(mainAddress);
                return resolve();
            } else {
                enqueueSnackbar("Error getting main address ", { variant: 'error' });
                return reject();
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I just want to understand why I get this error and any potential solutions or what I am doing wrong etc. below is the full error. If I comment out the `setThisLoading(false)` in the `.then()` of the `Promise.all()` the error goes away but my page never displays any content because I use `thisLoading` to conditionally render a loading wheel or the content.

```
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useContext                 useContext
2. useDebugValue              useDebugValue
3. useContext                 useContext
4. useRef                     useRef
5. useRef                     useRef
6. useRef                     useRef
7. useMemo                    useMemo
8. useEffect                  useEffect
9. useEffect                  useEffect
10. useDebugValue             useDebugValue
11. useContext                useContext
12. useState                  useState
13. useState                  useState
14. useState                  useState
15. useState                  useState
16. useState                  useState
17. useState                  useState
18. useState                  useState
19. useContext                useContext
20. useEffect                 useEffect
21. undefined                 useContext
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am just looking to understand why the `setThisLoading(false)` causes me to get this error.

### Update

The `useSnackbar()` hook is provided by an external libary notistack
https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack

Below is the code relating to `useProfileState()`

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';

const initialState = { loggedIn: false, loading: true, error: false }

const ProfileStateContext = createContext();
const ProfileDispatchContext = createContext();

const ProfileReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOGGED_IN':
            console.log("PROFILE CONTEXT - Logged in");
            return { ...state, loggedIn: true }
        case 'LOADED':
            console.log("PROFILE CONTEXT - Data loaded");
            return { ...state, loading: false, error: false }
        case 'LOADING':
            console.log("PROFILE CONTEXT - Data loading");
            return { ...state, loading: true, error: false }
        case 'ERROR':
            console.log("PROFILE CONTEXT - Error");
            return { ...state, loading: false, error: true }
        case 'ADD_USER':
            console.log("PROFILE CONTEXT - Adding user...");
            return { ...state, user: { ...action.payload } }
        case 'ADD_ORGANISATION':
            console.log("PROFILE CONTEXT - Adding organisation...");
            return { ...state, organisation: { ...action.payload } }
        case 'ADD_ROLES':
            console.log("PROFILE CONTEXT - Adding roles...");
            return { ...state, roles: [...action.payload] }
        case 'ADD_ORGANISATIONS':
            console.log("PROFILE CONTEXT - Adding organisations...");
            return { ...state, organisations: [...action.payload] }
        case 'ADD_ADDRESSES':
            console.log("PROFILE CONTEXT - Adding addresses...");
            return { ...state, addresses: [...action.payload] }
        case 'LOGOUT':
            console.log("PROFILE CONTEXT - Removing context data...");
            return initialState;
        default:
            console.error(`Unhandled action dispatched to user reducer, action type was: ${action.type}`);
            return state;
    }
}

const ProfileProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(ProfileReducer, initialState)

    return (
        <ProfileStateContext.Provider value={state}>
            <ProfileDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
                {children}
            </ProfileDispatchContext.Provider>
        </ProfileStateContext.Provider>
    );
};

const useProfileState = () => {
    const context = useContext(ProfileStateContext);

    if (context === undefined) {
        throw new Error('useProfileState must be used within a ProfileContextProvider')
    }

    return context;
};

const useProfileDispatch = () => {
    const context = useContext(ProfileDispatchContext);

    if (context === undefined) {
        throw new Error('useProfileDispatch must be used within a ProfileContextProvider')
    }

    return context;
};

export {
    ProfileProvider,
    useProfileDispatch,
    useProfileState
}
```

### Update 2

I have also tried chaining the promises and adding a dummy cleanup func as suggested, I still get the same error.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setThisLoading(true);
    if(organisation && addresses && !loading) {
        getMainContact()
            .then(() => {
                getMainAddress()
                    .then(() => {
                        getBillingContact()
                            .then(() => {
                                getBillingAddress()
                                    .then(() => {
                                        setThisLoading(false);
                                    })
                            })
                    })
            })
    }

    return () => {};
}, [organisation, addresses, loading])
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is hidden in `useSnackbar` or `useProfileState`. Can you show us the code?

Comment: @Martin I have updated my original question - TIA

Comment: I could not find anything suspicious in the custom hooks. Will the error go away when you comment-out the `useEffect`? Might help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Martin thats the first thing I tried and the error goes away, but again my content doesn't render, I seem to have narrowed it down to the `setThisLoading` line in the `.then` but I can't work out why this line would cause the error.

Comment: That's quite a pickle. Does the behavior change when you chain the promises? Or when you return a dummy *cleanup callback* from `useEffect` like `return () => {};` just to be sure.

Comment: @Martin, Just tried that, doesn't seem to stop the error, I have editited my question to include this code just to ensure were on the same page, Thanks for your continued help

Comment: I'm throwing more ideas at the wall: move your `const` declarations before the usage (I know this should make no difference because of hoisting but why not try) and chain the promises only toplevel: `.then(() =>getMainAddress()).then(() =>getBillingContact()).then(...`

Comment: I must start cooking dinner now or my wife kills me, but I will have a look later in the evening.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for your help, I actually found the problem was in a completely different component, the conditional rendering of the content caused the error to only show when loading was set to false hence the red herring. I will post the solution as an answer below

Comment: OK thank god. Thanks for letting me know. Otherwise I would have spend a sleepless night. All things React are rather dear to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem to be in a completely different component to the one the error was indicating towards. The `setThisLoading(false)` was a red herring as this just allowed the problem component to render therefore giving the error. The way I found this out was via Chrome’s console, I usually work in Firefox as this is my browser of choice but this time Chrome came to the rescue as it gave more information as to where the error was originating from.

The application I am building has the concept of user roles, allowing/denying users to perform certain tasks. I wrote some functions to assist in the disabling of buttons and/or not showing content based on the role the logged in user had. This is where the problem lies.

### Old RoleCheck.js

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { useProfileState } from '../../context/ProfileContext';

    //0 - No permission
    //1 - Read only
    //2 - Read/Write

    const _roleCheck = (realm, permission) => {

        const { organisation, organisations, roles, loading } = useProfileState();

        if(!loading) {

            //Get the RoleID for the current account
            const currentOrganisation = organisations.find(org => org.id === organisation.id);
            //Get the Role object by RoleID
            const currentRole = roles.find(role => role.id === currentOrganisation.roleId);

            if(currentRole[realm] === permission) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

    };

    export const roleCheck = (realm, permission) => {

        //Reversed boolean for button disabling
        if(_roleCheck(realm, permission)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    };

    export const RoleCheck = ({ children, realm, permission }) => {
        
        if(_roleCheck(realm, permission)) {
            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    { children }
                </React.Fragment>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <React.Fragment />
            );
        }

    };
```

### Usage of old RoleCheck.js

```
import { roleCheck } from '../Utils/RoleCheck';
...
<Button variant="outlined" disabled={roleCheck("organisation", 2)} color="primary">
    edit organisation
</Button>
```

### New RoleCheck.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { useProfileState } from '../../context/ProfileContext';

//0 - No permission
//1 - Read only
//2 - Read/Write

export const useRoleCheck = () => {

    const { organisation, organisations, roles, loading } = useProfileState();

    const _roleCheck = (realm, permission) => {
    
        if(!loading) {
    
            //Get the RoleID for the current account
            const currentOrganisation = organisations.find(org => org.id === organisation.id);
            //Get the Role object by RoleID
            const currentRole = roles.find(role => role.id === currentOrganisation.roleId);
    
            if(currentRole[realm] === permission) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    
    };

    const RoleCheckWrapper = ({ children, realm, permission }) => {
    
        if(_roleCheck(realm, permission)) {
            return (
                <React.Fragment>
                    { children }
                </React.Fragment>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <React.Fragment />
            );
        }
    
    };

    const roleCheck = (realm, permission) => {

        //Reversed boolean for button disabling
        if(_roleCheck(realm, permission)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    
    };

    return {
        roleCheck: roleCheck,
        RoleCheckWrapper: RoleCheckWrapper
    }

}
```

### Usage of new RoleCheck.js

```
import { useRoleCheck } from '../Utils/RoleCheck';
...
const RequiresRoleCheck = () => {

    const rc = useRoleCheck();

    return (
        <Button variant="outlined" disabled={rc.roleCheck("organisation", 2)} color="primary">
            edit organisation
        </Button>
    )

}
```

By turning my Role Check functions into a hook I am able to call hooks inside it and I am able to call the `useRoleCheck()` hook at the top level of components that need to use it therefore not breaking the rules of hooks!